# distance using Bluetooth connection of watch and iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bluetooth, watch

Can we calculate distance of iWatch paired with iPhone device using bluetooth ?

I tried location to get distance between both devices using  below, but I need to create simple single app to make it workable using either iPhone app or iWatch app.

```
#define d2r (M_PI / 180.0)

+(float) haversine_km:(float)lat1: (float)long1: (float)lat2: (float)long2
{
float dlong = (long2 - long1) * d2r;
float dlat = (lat2 - lat1) * d2r;
float a = pow(sin(dlat/2.0), 2) + cos(lat1*d2r) * cos(lat2*d2r) * pow(sin(dlong/2.0), 2); 
float c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a));
float d = 6367 * c;

return d;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking for? A fix to your code or some other procedure to determine locations or an app itself?

Comment: just need to check how much distance is my phone from my watch using bluetooth

Comment: Well, Bluetooth is not a distance measurement tool so it can not give you a distance out of the box. It is however a communication system which when establish between two devices may exchange data. This can possibly give you two interesting informations. One is the quality of communication (signal strength) which may in some cases be used to estimate the distance. And it can be used to communicate the geolocation of each of devices which can then be used to compute the distance. Could any of the two be helpful for you?

Comment: Well, it is possible to measure distance between two bluetooth devices, inline with with @MaticOblak response.  check if your iOS sdk provides information such as RSSI. RSSI information is specific to mobile OEMs SDK. Detailed read can be found here https://www.bluetooth.com/blog/proximity-and-rssi/

Comment: @ManivannanRadhakannan Thank you for contributing. Still I must insist that this is *estimation*, not measurement. I have to assume that the link you provided uses nearly perfect - laboratory data to have such nice results. In reality though there may be walls, it depends strongly on where your fingers are placed on your phone, it depends strongly on which direction your phone is facing, there are other signals effecting strength measurement... Still even the link says "we could have a fairly accurate estimate of the distance".

Comment: I agree they may be laboratory data, but in reality the radio interference can happen due to many reasons as you mentioned. But the signal strength(RSSI) is the prime indicator of relative distance, but it is the limitation of Bluetooth Specification till 5.0. With Bluetooth 5.1, they have introduced Angle of Attack feature, which is exactly you are looking for. https://www.bluetooth.com/blog/new-aoa-aod-bluetooth-capabilities/